# Dynamically injecting a specific factory based on route parameter fails for some reason

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-routing

I want to dynamically inject a factory into my Angular controller based on the route parameter. This is my route configuration:

```
$routeProvider
.when("/tables/:table",
{
    controller: "tableController",
    templateUrl: "/app/views/table.html",
    resolve: {
        "factory": function r($route) {
            return $injector.get($route.current.params.table + "Factory"); // Error!
        }
    }
})
```

For instance, when the route is `tables/employee`, I want an `employeeFactory` to be injected into `tableController`, and so on.

Unfortunately, this configuration does not work — I am getting an [`Unknown provider: employeeFactory`](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/unpr?p0=employeeFactory) error in the `r` function.

On the other hand, I can instead pass an `$injector` service directly to the `tableController` and successfully resolve `employeeFactory` there:

```
(function (angular) {
    var tableController = function ($routeParams, $injector) {
        // employeeFactory resolves successfully here!
        var factory = $injector.get($routeParams.table + "Factory");
    };

    angular.module("appModule").controller("tableController", tableController);
})(angular);
```

However, I do not like this approach because it follows the [service locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). I would really like `factory` to be injected using routing configuration and not this ugly workaround.

So, why Angular is throwing an error when using `$injector.get()` with `resolve`, but successfully resolves the factory inside of the `tableController`? I am using Angular 1.4.4.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your config block please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently use `$injector` that was injected into `config` block, and it differs from `$injector` that is injected anywhere else. The former [acts on service providers](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.6/src/auto/injector.js#L633), the latter [acts on service instances](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.6/src/auto/injector.js#L641).

It should be

```
    "factory": function r($route, $injector) {
        return $injector.get($route.current.params.table + "Factory");
    }
```

Comment: Wow, that helped! Didn't know that. Thanks a lot.